# Dynamically setting the width of en element to match that of a neighboring element

Tags: jquery, html, css

My html is as follows:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="image"><img src="" alt="" /></div>
    <div class="caption"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="image"><img src="" alt="" /></div>
    <div class="caption"></div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to set the width of each `.caption` as the same as the height of `.image img`

Am I on the right track?

```
$(".caption").each(function(){
    var imgheight = $(this).closest(".image img").height();
    $(this).css({
        width: imgheight
    });
});
```

Comment: The [jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com) are amazing, and if you look at the description of the [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) method, you see that it doesn't do that. Consider [`prev`](http://api.jquery.com/prev) and/or [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
var imgheight = $(this).closest('.row').find(".image img").height();
```

or

```
var imgheight = $(this).prev(".image").find("img").height();
```

You can also use [children()](http://api.jquery.com/children) instead of [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find)

[closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) gives the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

Comment: Thank you, all the examples are great. The links through to docs helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
var imgheight = $(this).parents(".row").find(".image img").height();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(".caption").each(function(){
  var imgheight = $(this).parent().find(".image img").height();
  $(this).width(imgheight);
});
```

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsbin.com/OtuMajA/1/edit)